# Matrix integration by parts

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, matrices

It seems to me that the integration by parts rule carries over simply to the matrix case. This can be seen by applying: $(AB)' = A'B + AB'$ and then integrating for square (time dependent) complex matrices.

I wanted to check what the rule should be exactly to integrate:

$\int_{t=0}^{t=T} A(t)B(t) dt$

where $A,B$ are square complex matrices depending on $t$. (please assume any differentiation/smoothness level required).

Comment: When you say "complex", are you saying that the numbers in each matrix come from the set of complex numbers?

Comment: Yes! I didn't just mean a difficult to understand matrix!

Comment: Do you think there's a rule to integrate $\int_0^T a(t)b(t)\,{\rm d}t$ for scalar functions $a(t)$ and $b(t)$? Really, you already found it: integration by parts.

Comment: I just wanted confirmation that nothing went wrong in the matrix case, I didn't think it was likely that it would. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly $\int_u^v A'(t)B(t)dt=A(v)B(v)-A(u)B(u)-\int_u^vA(t)B'(t)dt$.